# ExpandableListView and getItemViewType

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Does ExpandableListAdapter support any functions as BaseAdapter overriding getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount which I could create various view types in

```
getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExpandableListAdapter doesn't but it's subclass BaseExpandableListAdapter does. Therefore, indirectly, the other subclasses CursorTreeAdapter, ResourceCursorTreeAdapter, SimpleCursorTreeAdapter and SimpleExpandableListAdapter do too.

Those methods are:

```
    public int getChildType(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition)
    public int getChildTypeCount()
```

Comment: beware, they both were added in API8

Comment: Upvoting this in 2019! Needed some archaic implementation using ExpandableListView and this was helpful as I completely forgot this function name because of using recyclerView for last 4+ years. LOL!